# quasiquotation with sjlabelled::val_labels()

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm trying to use `sjlabelled::val_labels()` to apply value labels where the variable name, the value being labelled, and the label are all quasiquoted.

Here's an example without using quasiquotation:

```r
library(sjlabelled)
library(rlang)
library(magrittr)

mtcars.test <- mtcars %>%
  val_labels(
    gear = c("foo" = 1)
  )
attributes(mtcars.test$gear)
#> $labels
#> foo 
#>   1
```

It's easy to use quasiquotation for the variable name, and the value name seems to be automatically unquoted if it's a character string:

```r
variable <- "gear"
value <- 1
mtcars.test <- mtcars %>%
  val_labels(
    !!variable := c("foo" = value)
  )
attributes(mtcars.test$gear)
#> $labels
#> foo 
#>   1
```

Where I get stuck is unquoting the label name:

```r
label <- "foo"
mtcars.test <- mtcars %>%
  val_labels(
    !!variable := c(!!label := !!value)
  )
#> `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument
```

The documentation for `?val_labels` discusses quasiquotation, but doesn't contain an example that unquotes each of these three elements. One workaround is to build the named vector separately and unquote it:

```r
vector <- value
names(vector) <- label
mtcars.test <- mtcars %>%
  val_labels(
    !!variable := !!vector
  )
attributes(mtcars.test$gear)
#> $labels
#> foo 
#>   1
```

This gets the job done, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can do this with the one-liner without having to assign the named vector.

Comment: You can't use `:=` within `c()`. You could use `setNames(value, label)` instead.